# How to get first key with special value in redis?

Tags: java, redis

I have a key value storage on redis with string 5 character key and a value of 0 or 1, I use redis template for set data on redis. now I want to get first key with value of 0, is that possible?

```
private StringRedisTemplate template;

@Autowired
public CodeBuilderRepository(StringRedisTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public void insertCode(String code) {
    template.opsForValue().set(code, "0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's **NO** order for Redis keys, since there's no order for hash.

If you only want to find a key with a specific value, you can do it in two ways.

1. Use `RANDOMKEY` command to get a random key, and check if the value satisfies. Repeat the process until you get the right key.
2. Use `SCAN` command to iterate the keys space, and check if the value satisfies.